# Can we use Openstack Identity API for creating Single sign on for web application

Tags: identity, openstack, keystone

Can we use Openstack Identity API to Create Single Sign on for web Application. If it is possible can somebody give an idea where to start. Like how to get started with Identity API.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but why bother? There are so many other standards and libraries that would do a better job.

Comment: I am trying to build identity as service. Is there any better api to build this kind of system